# How to insert data into oracle 10g database through .txt file using PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle10g

How to insert data into oracle 10g database through .txt file using PL/SQL ? Inserting data , row-wise using query takes too much time. Is there any online resource where i can directly import data into my oracle 1databse.

Comment: Does the file exist on the database server?  Or on a client machine?  Could it be moved to the database server?  Is PL/SQL an actual requirement?  Or are you just trying to improve the performance of the load?

Comment: How are you currently loading?

Comment: Actually i wants to load a big number of student records (1000 students ) into my database which is saved in my laptop  as a file students.txt  and different attributes are separated through tab. If i starts inserting of tuples one by one using sql query like  INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(A,B,C,D, . . . . . .)  then it will be take too much time . Since i knows PL/SQL and SQL currently thats why i am interested in PL/SQL. If it is not possible(OR possible but difficult) through PL/SQL then tell me other ways of doing this . My database and text file both are in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may sound funny, but it is the simplest way I know:

- insert data into MS EXCEL (using tab as delimiter to fill columns)
- populate a new column with sql statement / filling values with cell pointers e.g. ="insert into mytable values('"&A$1&"');"
- click to autofill to populate all 1000 rows
- copy&paste to .sql file

Unles you have to do it regularly it's an easy solution, otherwise you should probably write your own parser.